# Changing list of time zone offset numbers to current times with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am displaying a list of names and their time zone offset numbers in a table. The offset numbers are their time zone's offset from UTC. I need to change all of the offset numbers to show the current time in the person's time zone using JavaScript or jQuery.

What I would like to happen is the offset numbers would be replaced with the current date/time from the `calcTime` function... any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="name">John Doe</div><div class="timezone">-5</div>
<div class="name">Jane Doe</div><div class="timezone">3</div>
<div class="name">Jim Smith</div><div class="timezone">7</div>
<div class="name">Cathy Jones</div><div class="timezone">-3</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        function calcTime(offset) {
            // create Date object for current location
            d = new Date();
            // convert to msec
            // add local time zone offset
            // get UTC time in msec
            utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
            // create new Date object for different city
            // using supplied offset
            nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
            // return time as a string
            return "The local time is " + nd.toLocaleString();
        }

        $(".timezone").each(function(){
            h = $(this).find(".timezone").text();
            element.innerHTML = calcTime(h); 
        //alert(calcTime('-5'));
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to adjust a date time to show in a different timezone?

Comment: Sorry, I'll adjust the question. Basically, we have a list of their timezone's offset from UTC. I need to show that person's local time beside their name.

Comment: The code has some logic problems and will not work as written. But, the first time through (even if this code would work), the `-5` or `7` or whatever _offset_ that _used to be in the HTML element_ has been replaced with a string. The second time through that string produces and invalid date (since it is no longer an _offset_).

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you for your reply. I know that the calcTime function works, as I found it elsewhere and tested it, but the code I have looping through the timezone divs doesn't work because i'm a javascript noob and I'm not sure how to fix it...

Comment: You're iterating through the elements with the class "timezone", trying to find the elements with the class "timezone" within those elements.

Comment: @RandyCasburn `3600000*offset` will coerce `offset` to a number.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I think you missed it - the OP's intent is to _replace_ the text content of the `div` with class `timezone` (from `-5`) with a string `"The local time is ..."`

Comment: Ah, would have been clearer with that string "The local time is ..." in the original comment. `text()` always returns a string, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are attempting to achieve (with significant changes).

Note the use of `setInterval()` rather than set time out and the structural changes to the HTML.

```js
const utc = document.querySelector('.utc');
const collection = document.querySelectorAll('.timezone');
const outputs = document.querySelectorAll('.output');
const localeTZoffSet = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60 * 3600000;

setInterval(() => {
  utc.textContent = calcTime(0);
  collection.forEach((element, idx) => {
    outputs[idx].textContent = calcTime(element.textContent);
  });
});

function calcTime(offset) {
  return "The local time is " + new Date(Date.now() + localeTZoffSet + (3600000 * offset)).toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

```html
<div>UTC: <span class="utc"></span></div>
<div class="name">John Doe - <span class="output"></span></div>
<div class="timezone">-5</div>
<div class="name">Jane Doe - <span class="output"></span></div>
<div class="timezone">3</div>
<div class="name">Jim Smith - <span class="output"></span></div>
<div class="timezone">7</div>
<div class="name">Cathy Jones - <span class="output"></span></div>
<div class="timezone">-3</div>
```

Comment: Wow this is really close! It looks like this code is adding (or subtracting) the offset from the local time, rather than from UTC time. Is there a way to get it to use the UTC?

Comment: Yeah - sorry, forget the local offset. The edit should do it now.

Comment: I am in GMT-5 timezone... And the time shown for "John Doe" is off by 2 hours.

Comment: EDT is on the money for me. Right now it shows 12:42 for UTC and 7:42 for EDT (-5). @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: I'm in Montreal, Canada, and your snippet shows https://imgur.com/H4QobMR -- I did not noticed the AM the first time... So that is way more than 2 hours offset to reality. -- Actually 7:49 PM

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - yep, I was subtracting a negative rather than adding. So that is fixed. But I don't understand the two hour difference. Please try now.

Comment: John Doe has the correct time for me now ;)

Answer (score 0):

With @RandyCasburn 's help, I was able to get this to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     const collection = document.querySelectorAll('.timezone');
     const outputs = document.querySelectorAll('.output');

     function calcTime(offset) {
         d = new Date();
         utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
         nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
         return nd.toLocaleString();
     }
     setInterval(() => {
        collection.forEach((element, idx) => {
           outputs[idx].textContent = calcTime(element.textContent);
           $(".timezone").hide();
        });
    });
});

<div class="name">John Doe - <span class="output"></span></div>
<div class="timezone">-5</div>
<div class="name">Jane Doe - <span class="output"></span></div>
<div class="timezone">3</div>
<div class="name">Jim Smith - <span class="output"></span></div>
<div class="timezone">7</div>
<div class="name">Cathy Jones - <span class="output"></span></div>
<div class="timezone">-3</div>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: I edited my answer - please consider upvoting and accepting my answer. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If I get the problem correctly.. .oO(lol)
You wish to display the realtime of each users based on their UTC offset.

I would have the user timezone in a data attribute to make sure to keep it handy.
*(See changes made in your HTML below)*
Then:

- Create a local time object (where the page renders)
- From the local time, you can get the UTC offset and the local hour.
- Calculate the offset between the page viewer and the "other user".
  Meaning... As a page viewer I am in GMT-5 timezone, the first user (in your HTML) has a zero offset with me. Correct?
- So starting from the local time and local GMT offset, add the *"real time difference"*.
- Sadly, the `.setHours()` method return milliseconds... So create a new date object with it.
- Have it to a string and remove the part after "GMT-..." since this part is not accurate now.

Here is a demo with all the console.logs:

```js
console.clear();

$(document).ready(function () {
  function calcTime(offset) {
    // That is a date object with the user's timezone
    let refDate = new Date();

    // So what is the user's timezone?
    let userTimezone = refDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    console.log("userTimezone", userTimezone);

    // What is the user's Hour?
    let localHour = refDate.getHours();
    console.log("localHour", localHour);

    // Make the calculation here
    let timeZoneDiff = offset + userTimezone;
    console.log("timeZoneDiff", timeZoneDiff);

    // Set the hour... But we still are in a "timezoned object"
    // and the .setHours returns milliseconds. ;(
    let hourRearanged = refDate.setHours(localHour + timeZoneDiff);
    console.log("hourRearanged", hourRearanged);

    // So re-generate a date object from that "arranged hour"
    let semiResult = new Date(hourRearanged).toString();
    console.log("semiResult were the part after GMT is wrong:", semiResult);

    console.log("---------------------------------------");
    
    // Rturn the part before "GMT"
    return semiResult.split("GMT")[0];
  }

  setInterval(() => {
    $(".name").each(function (index, element) {
      h = parseInt($(element).data("timezone"));
      $(element).next(".userTime").html(calcTime(h));
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name" data-timezone="-5">John Doe (GMT-5)</div>
<div class="userTime">-5</div>
<div class="name" data-timezone="3">Jane Doe (GMT+3)</div>
<div class="userTime">3</div>
<div class="name" data-timezone="7">Jim Smith (GMT+7)</div>
<div class="userTime">7</div>
<div class="name" data-timezone="-3">Cathy Jones (GMT-3)</div>
<div class="userTime">-3</div>
```

Run in full page mode please...