# Construct Moment JS format same as new Date() format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using the Javascript `new Date()` to store the date/time for a database entry. It's storing it in this format:

- `2021-01-20T16:59:34.768+00:00`

Now, I need to get the exact same format from Moment JS, I've tried using: `moment().format()` but there's a difference between the two:

- Moment JS: `2021-01-20T16:59:14.237+00:00`
- JS new Date: `2021-01-20T16:59:14+00:00`

It seems that `.format()` doesn't match them up? I've also tried using `.toDate()` which doesn't seem to give me the same format.

Need to get Moment JS to format the same as how `new Date()` would

Comment: Why not just use the native Date object?

Comment: try in moment `new moment(new Date()).toISOString()`

Comment: @RandyCasburn maybe he works with timezones or something complex

Comment: @Joseph - [working in timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818270/changing-list-of-time-zone-offset-numbers-to-current-times-with-javascript/65818776#65818776) is not difficult.

Comment: i like your answer but when it comes to the time part it would be critical and i wouldn't implement it in a native way to not forget any edge cases

Comment: I get `Thu Jan 21 2021 08:17:35 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ` as a default format for `new Date()`